# How can I barbecue salmon steak?

Tags: barbecue, salmon

I have two Salmon steaks that I would like to Barbeque. What are some effective techniques for barbecuing salmon?

Answer (score 8):

Buy a cedar plank. Soak it in salted water for a couple of hours

Rub the salmon with olive oil and season it with a little bit of salt, I use kosher salt or smoked sea salt but regular table salt will work just fine. Then put the salmon on top of the plank, skin side down. Then put the plank on the BBQ. You can see the fish cook, it will get pinkish-white starting from the skin and traveling up. If your grill has a top, close it and cook for about 20-30 minutes. Check it to make sure it's not drying out. Internal temp should be around 130 or so.

Comment: also great is to marinade the salmon in Italian dressing for ~10 minutes (at most 30 so that the salmon doesn't disintegrate when you try to pick it up).

Answer (score 4):

I like making a dry rub with brown sugar, paprika, chipotle powder, thyme, black pepper, salt, and parsley. To cook, dredge in a bit of olive oil, then pat with the rub. It'll caramelise wonderfully and lends a really nice taste - smoky sweet with a bit of a bite.

Comment: You're making me hungry.

Answer (score 1):

A lil' evoo, sprinkle with Emeril's fish rub and smoke skin side down between 200-250 for 3-3.5 hours...yum!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I've ever done for BBQ salmon is to put something on it (I usually just put a couple lemon slices, sometimes a bit of BBQ sauce) wrap it in foil, and cook it.

Answer (score 0):

i love doing it this way, it's not quite "BBQ" other than that it is cooked on the bbq itself.

put the steaks on some foil then salt & pepper them.  lay on top of them some lemon slices and some sprigs of oregano. put a splash of white wine on it then seal the foil into a tent shape with the steak inside.   pull off after about 10 minutes or until the steaks are how you like them.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way is to grill with a slice of bacon and slice of lemon on top.  Set the bacon and lemon aside while flipping, then put back on top.